# ubuntu 14.04 change windows dimension

Tags: unity, 14.04, settings

May I change the opening dimensions of applications?
I have tried installing ccsm but there is no more the item "widows rules" and I did not found something similar that could help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you wouldn't be able to do so in Compiz-config Settings Manager (CCSM) anymore. Is it possible that you just need to install a plugin in order to get that feature back?

Anyway, I would recommend Devil's Pie for this. It's not specific to Compiz, but works with any X desktop, meaning that it's also useful with Gnome Shell, KDE, LXDE, Xfce, etc, which normally don't use Compiz.

Devil's Pie is in the Ubuntu archives as [devilspie (click to install)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/devilspie) and there are also a GUI application for it: [gdevilspie (click to install)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gdevilspie)

You can read more about Devil's Pie in the Ubuntu Community help pages: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie